# Is there a web app to curate Instagram-user galleries (lists)?

Tags: photos, instagram

Curious if there is a web app that will let you curate lists of Instagram users - ideally in a gallery form that is easy to browse.

Bonus points if it can add users of other photo sharing services and display their photos...

Comment: http://inkstagram.com is the closest I've seen, but only lets you create albums based on hashtags.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Webstagram](http://web.stagram.com/).

> You can ....
>
> - View photos from the people you follow
> - Like, Unlike and Comment, Un-Comment on photos
> - Follow and Unfollow other users
> - See your followers and following
> - Browse popular photos / tags / users
> - AND MANY OTHER STUNNING FEATURES...!

Comment: there are a number of excellent web-based Instagram viewers - Webstagram doesn't have the functionality I'm specifically looking for